# How do you take off body armor in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

It's kind of hard to shop for clothes with a big bullet proof vest on.  Is there a way to take off the armor after missions, or at least hide it?

Comment: You got get yourself killed? Or try getting shot at untill it goes away?

Comment: @Lyron Doesn't work.  It even remains when you log out and log back in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just hit the Select button on the PS3 or back on the Xbox 360 to access Inventory. There you can turn off the Armor option

Answer (score 5):

Go to your closet in your house. There you can deselect body armor. Scroll down to another option in the shirt or pants section and select something else.

Or, on xbox, press back, go to inventory and press body armor and change it to none.

Comment: I suspected as much.  Unfortunate that you need a house to take off the body armor.  Feels like the clothing stores should have an option for it.

Answer (score 0):

you hold the back button, go into inventory and you can remove it from there.